# How could I build components for a composable loot system like one in RuneScape without using OOP?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I looked at some entity component systems, and noticed that they sometimes list static polymorphism as a feature, and ECSs and data oriented programming seem to be touted as holy grail of modern game design, so that's my focus here on the "without OOP" here, not sure how else I can word it, if some data being implemented with dynamic polymorphism is unavoidable, that's fine.

Since I am mimicking one system of RuneScape, because that's the system that actually exists in a successful game and it interests me the most, there are several gotchas standing in the way of "just run weighted random algorithm through arrays and be done with it", which is what I'd do had I not set this arbitrary restriction on myself.

Here's incomplete list of them:

1. Same monster in different area has a different loot table;
2. Some monsters have unique drops that when received, prevent anything else from dropping even if otherwise there would've been multiple rolls of several things;
3. Some monsters are part of what you could call "procedurally generated quests" wherein if player is currently in such quest, a specific monster drops a specific item, real quests can also do this, with chances or certain guarantees;
4. Some monsters have pre-roll tables that roll before main table and items are selected differently there, also it may cancel main table drops in similar way the uniques do, yet differently at the same time;
5. Some monsters have tertiary drop tables that roll independent of main table, each drop is rolled on sequentially and it can produce more than one item, all items from list may be given, or none even;
6. Rolls are recursive - a drop table is a valid item for the purpose of loot possible from a table, in this case a table must be rolled on in its own unique way to compute what exactly player will receive;
7. Some drops depend on permanent game state, e.g. after player completes quest, a new item is added to an existing drop table;
8. Some drop tables can be rolled on several times, each roll being independent from one another;
9. Some game features unrelated to awarding loot to player may be implemented using drop tables where drops are arbitrary concepts such as slayer tasks in slayer skill in RuneScape, this in particular depends on player combat levels, quests to determine what can be given as a task to the player, for example if task requires specific item for player to do it and they cannot equip it due to missing requirements, it may not be a part of table until player can;
10. Some loot is just 1 item of specific ID, other can be a random range of items, even loot weights can be affected by items worn.
11. Some loot tables are "general" and are shared by all monsters/tables.

I more or less know how I would *attempt* to implement this in traditional OOP style, first I'd go for something close to this:

```cpp
class loot {/* pure virtual interface */};

// different item amounts which are maybe random solved
class loot_item: public loot {/* item id, fixed item count is awarded to player*/};
class loot_item_range: public loot {/* item id, [min; max] count of item is awarded to player */};

class one_of: public loot {/* implementation for weighted random that selects and evaluates one loot item from internal list */};

// pre-roll table problem solved
class any_of: public loot {/* rolls on each loot in list and bails on first hit on any table */};

// might need a better name
class all_of: public loot {/* rolls on each loot in list but never bails regardless of any drops received or skipped */};

class disruptor: public loot {/* wrapper that may modify the wrapped table based on game events */};
```

And honestly even OOP system gets out of hand fairly fast, really, what I'm looking for is composability above all else, high performance is great also, but one player normally can't be killing even hundreds of things per frame in a game with balanced combat system, I suppose.